# How to develop a dynamic webpage?

Tags: web, ide

I am used to program webpages with PHP and MySQL on the serverside and LessCSS, jQuery and HTML5 on the client side. I now have a slightly bigger project to do and I do ask me what is the best way to develop a websize such like twitter. The aim is to have an user experience without "halting" the website everytime you click a link.

So in fact that shouldn't be a big problem. It's a little AJAX for the async operations and a little CSS3 for animations. But I asked me how to develop it most comfortable. Which framework are a must have? How can I make database more simply? And finnaly: What is a good IDE for web development?

Answer (score 0):

This question is like asking what is the best club in world, every one has one answer, but that doesn't mean that it will be your answer also.

If you are comfortable with PHP, MySql and jQuery, then it would be logical to go that way.

When it comes to IDE again it depened from person to person, my choice is usually Emacs, but Eclipse is also good choice. Again it doesn't mean that you or someone else will agree with this choice. Again it all comes to what you are comfortable with, are you working alone, or not on this project etc.....

Comment: Yes thats right, but I think it is important to know what other people think, maybe there are better solutions out there that I never heard of.

Comment: If fast insert and update of data is goal of the game try to normalize db, a lot, on the other hand if you are going to read often, and produce lot of statistics (where join will be needed) don't normalize a lot. Even de-normalize DB. About language, again question is were it will be hosed, as far as I looked most providers can give you php + mysql site for small amount of $, and in my opinion it is something that should be taken into account also.